# Confusion about nonlinear transformation of gamma and inverse-gamma distributions

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, data-transformation, gamma-distribution, inverse-gamma-distribution

I have a question about the variance of a transformed random variable, illustrated by a particular example.  Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ and $Y_1, ..., Y_n$ be independent random variables drawn from an exponential distribution with rate parameter $k$.  Also, let $X = X_1 + ... + X_n$ and $Y = Y_1 + ... + Y_n$.  Then $X$ and $Y$ follow a gamma distribution with mean $\frac{n}{k}$ and variance $\frac{n}{k^2}$.  Now let $A(X, Y) = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{X}{Y}}$.  Using a linear Taylor series approximation for $A$ gives the variance Var[A] approximately equal to $\frac{Y^2 Var[X] + X^2 Var[Y]}{(X + Y)^4}$.  If we now consider the reciprocals $W = \frac{1}{X}$ and $Z = \frac{1}{Y}$, $W$ and $Z$ follow an inverse-gamma distribution with mean $\frac{k}{n - 1}$ and variance $\frac{k^2}{(n - 1)^2 (n - 2)}$.  Substitution gives $A(W, Z) = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{Z}{W}}$ and the same formula as above for $Var[A]$, with $X$ and $Y$ replaced by $Z$ and $W$ (or by $W$ and $Z$).

Here comes my question.  If $n = 2$, then $X$ and $Y$ have a finite variance, whereas $W$ and $Z$ have an infinite variance, so the approximation for $Var[A]$ would be finite in one case and infinite in the other.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Variance should be a positive real number (a constant), but your claimed variance value $\frac{Y^2 Var[X] + X^2 Var[Y]}{(X + Y)^4}$ is a **random variable** and not a constant. Please explain further...

Comment: The exact distribution of $A$ -- and its variance, are quite well known, of course. But even if your calculations were correct, it wouldn't surprise me that two approximations might not be anything alike (nor indeed, necessarily close to the true value), since it's relatively easy to find oneself in a situation where such approximations may be arbitrarily poor.

Comment: @DilipSarwate -- Sorry, the Taylor series is an expansion around particular values of X and Y, such as their mean values.  Those are the values for X and Y that should be used in the approximate variance formula.  -- Paul

Comment: @Glen_b -- Since my original post, I have learned that A(X, Y) has a beta distribution.  Based on some sample calculations, it seems that my formula for the variance of A(X, Y) is not a bad approximation, so I guess that means that the formula for the variance of A(W, Z) is no good.  I may have oversimplified the problem in my original post -- I am actually interested in the case where the Xi and Yi exponential distributions may have different rate parameters, and the number of Xi and Yi samples, nx and ny, may be different.  -- Paul